# Non-compatible print server

Tags: network-shares, network-printer

I have a HP P1006 and a TP-Link TL-PS110U.

My printer is not in the compatibility list of this print server, and it also says "Not compatible with host based printers" on top of its list.

Is there any way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 ways to successfully network host-based printers:

1. Connect them via a sharing PC
2. Use a certified compatible printserver

I found someone on the internet recommending the Zonet ZPS2112 for your printer - but I have never heard of that brand, so I cannot really recommend it. HP make a number of printservers:

J7942G HP Jetdirect en3700 External Print Server (USB, 10/100TX)

J7951G HP Jetdirect ew2400 802.11g Wireless and Fast Ethernet External Print Server

J7988G HP Jetdirect en1700 External Print Server

Unfortunately, HP's website does not list any of them as accessories for your printer, so I cannot suggest one of those either.

Final recommendation? Either buy a new printer or share it from a PC. If you buy a new printer I would suggest one that is NOT host-based, so you can use your printserver. This probably means you need to avoid HP if you want to keep the price down. You might also prefer to get one that already has a network interface, to make your life easier...